# Почему обьект не на нулевых координатах?

Tags: c#, unity3d

У меня есть объект с rect transform, мне нужно его перенести на определённые координаты, например 0x 0y. Пробую это сделать и в итоге обьект не на нулевых координатах, а на 771х и 266.1286y. Положение rect transform по центру. В чём может быть проблема и как это решить?

```
    public Transform JoystickTransform;
    public int JoyTransform;
    void Start()
    {
        JoyTransform = PlayerPrefs.GetInt("JoyTransform");   
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {
        if (JoyTransform == 0)
        {
            JoystickTransform.position = new Vector2(0, 0);
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Вангую:

Твой обьект в иерархии находится не дочерним от сцены, а дочерним от другого обьекта.

И выходит ситуация что ты перемещаешь на нулевые координаты (например локальные[относительно родителя]) а смотришь на глобальные значения.

Или же наоборот - перемещаешь в глобальной системе поординат и смотришь на локальные значения.

Присваивая вот так:

```
JoystickTransform.position = new Vector2(0, 0);
```

Ты присваиваешь ноль в глобальной системе координат.

А потом смотришь в инспекторе на позицию и смотришь на локальную систему координат.

Если ты перетащишь обьект по иерархии в корень а потом переместишь уже в (0,0) то увидишь что и вправду теперь будет показываться (0,0)

---

Соответственно кроме `.position` существует еще и `.localPosition`